# ¿Cómo condicionar una consulta MySQL row_number?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mariadb, backend

Buen día, tengo una tabla llamada aplications, la cual guarda un historial de estados (resolution) de clientes como historial.

```
0 : en validacion, 
1 : aceptado, 
2 : rechazado, 
4 : activo
```

El objetivo es obtener el último estado del cliente priorizando el estado 4 antes que los demás si es únicamente estado 2.
Es decir, si mi último estado es 2 pero antes de eso hay un 4, debería de devolver el estado 4 en caso contrario siempre devolverá el último.

Tengo el siguiente Query que devuelve el último estado del cliente:

```
select b.id, b.first_name, a.resolution, a.rn
        from (
          select a.*,
              row_number() over (
                partition by a.clientdata_id
                order by a.id desc) as rn
            from applications a
        ) a
LEFT JOIN clientdata as b on  a.clientdata_id = b.id
WHERE a.rn = 1
```

Con la herramienta row_number() declaro una columna llamada rn (row number) obteniendo siempre el último estado del cliente.

¿Cómo puedo condicionar y priorizar el objetivo anteriormente explicado?

Espero puedan apoyarme.

Comment: ¿La versión de mySQL que utilizas soporta CTE's (8 o superior)?

Comment: No sabría responderte, ¿Cómo seria la operación que mencionas?

Comment: Si te refieres a alguna _operación_ para averiguar la versión, puedes ejecutar en la línea de comandos `mysql –V` para verla (¡lo he googleado ahora mismo!).

Comment: Hablaba de tu respuesta amigo sobre el problema!!, de todas formas te anexo que efectivamente es la versión posterior a la 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que puedes lograr el resultado dividiendo el problema de esta manera:

- Conservar la base de la consulta que actualmente te da la información del último estado por cliente
- Realizar una consulta bastante similar a la primera, que nos entregue información del último estado para un cliente, pero que tome en cuenta solo los estados 4, que son los que van a tomar precedencia
- Hacer una última consulta *mezclando* los resultados de las dos consultas anteriores. Es en esta consulta cuando, si existe un resultado para estado 4, mostramos ese resultado, y si no, mostramos el que nos devuelve la consulta original.

Para conseguirlo, podemos valernos de dos CTE's que contengan los primeros dos pasos y ensamblar el resultado en la consulta final, tomando en cuenta que cualquier cliente que aparezca en el CTE del estado priorizado, aparecerá también en la consulta original.

El código dice más que mil palabras:

```
with
UltimoEstado as (
select b.id, b.first_name, a.resolution, a.rn
  from (select a.resolution, row_number() over (partition by a.clientdata_id order by a.id desc) as rn
          from applications a
       ) a
       inner join clientdata as b on  a.clientdata_id = b.id
WHERE a.rn = 1
)
,
EstadoPrioritario as (
select b.id, b.first_name, a.resolution, a.rn
  from (select a.resolution, row_number() over (partition by a.clientdata_id order by a.id desc) as rn
          from applications a
         where a.resolution = 4
       ) a
       inner join clientdata as b on  a.clientdata_id = b.id
WHERE a.rn = 1
)
select   UltimoEstado.id
       , UltimoEstado.first_name
       , case when EstadoPrioritario.resolution is not null then EstadoPrioritario.resolution else UltimoEStado.resolution end resolution
  from UltimoEstado
       left join EstadoPrioritario on EstadoPrioritario.id = UltimoEstado.id
```

Como puedes observar, he hecho algunos cambios en la consulta original

- Cambiar el `left join` por un inner join (en un buen diseño no debieras tener aplicaciones huerfanas, si las hay, regresa al `left join`.
- No traer todos los campos, sino solo `resolution`, que es el único que se usa en la consulta superior. Se que es una optimización que de todas formas es muy probable que haga el motor, pero prefiero expresarme con ese grado de precision).

Comment: Funciona la priorización, disculpa, Si quisiera que ésta priorización funcione únicamente si se encuentran en estado 2 ¿Cómo lo haría? haría mas variables priorizando el 0, 1 por encima del 4?

Comment: No sabría decir, habría que ver a detalle el resultado que esperas. Considero que esa sería una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias amigo

Comment: Efectivamente, realiza variables priorizando el 0, 1 y funciona correctamente, realiza lo que esperaba, en verdad agradezco el apoyo que me brindaste

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda, un saludo!